# Replacing multiple strings with some strings containing "." and affinity to other string(s) using sed

Tags: sed

I've spent an hour each day searching for ways to use sed for replacing below sample data as practice.
Hope someone could guide and correct me on using sed properly to achieve the right output.

sample.txt

```
User's name is adam
Account's name is adam_acc
User's name is adam.eve
Account's name is adam.eve_acc
```

Output trying to achieve:

```
User's name is user_1
Account's name is user_3
User's name is user_2
Account's name is user_4
```

Attempt tried:

```
$ sed 's/\<adam\>/user_1/g; 
s/\<adam\.eve\>/user_2/g; 
s/\<adam\_acc\>/user_3/g;
s/\<adam\.eve_acc\>/user_4/g' sample.txt
```

Attempt's output:

```
User's name is user_1
Account's name is user_3
User's name is user_1.eve
Account's name is user_1.eve_acc
```

Below is the bash version I am currently using:

```
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Material which I had read for more info:

```
https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/sed-regular-expressions.html#sed-regular-expressions
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk` you could try following once. Written and tested with your shown samples.

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/^adam$/)         { $i="user_1" }
    if($i~/^adam_acc$/)     { $i="user_3" }
    if($i~/^adam\.eve$/)    { $i="user_2" }
    if($i~/^adam\.eve_acc$/){ $i="user_4" }
  }
}
1' Input_file
```

I have used regex to evaluate above values in fields you could directly use `==` also with values(to save escaping part etc)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                        ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){                        ##Traversing through all fields here.
    if($i~/^adam$/)         { $i="user_1" }  ##Checking if field is adam then set it to user_1 here.
    if($i~/^adam_acc$/)     { $i="user_3" }  ##Checking if field is adam_acc then set it to user_3 here.
    if($i~/^adam\.eve$/)    { $i="user_2" }  ##Checking if field is adam.eve then set it to user_2 here.
    if($i~/^adam\.eve_acc$/){ $i="user_4" }  ##Checking if field is adam\.eve_acc then set it to user_4 here.
  }
}
1                                            ##Printing current line here.
' Input_file                                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks so much for putting so much effort in further sharing the explanation using awk. :D
Really appreciate it!

Comment: @Yong, Your welcome, we all are here for learning and sharing, cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

Move the longer patterns to the beginning of `sed` command:

```sh
sed 's/\<adam\.eve_acc\>/user_4/g; s/\<adam_acc\>/user_3/g; s/\<adam\.eve\>/user_2/g; s/\<adam\>/user_1/g;' file
```

Else, `\<adam\>` finds `adam` in `adam.eve` and `adam.eve_acc` and replaces them before `s/\<adam\.eve_acc\>/user_4/g` comes into play.

Note there is no need to escape the  `_` char.

See [an online demo](https://ideone.com/wb4jN4):

```sh
s="User's name is adam
Account's name is adam_acc
User's name is adam.eve
Account's name is adam.eve_acc"
sed 's/\<adam\.eve_acc\>/user_4/g; s/\<adam_acc\>/user_3/g; s/\<adam\.eve\>/user_2/g; s/\<adam\>/user_1/g;' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
User's name is user_1
Account's name is user_3
User's name is user_2
Account's name is user_4
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to mask bunch of user names. Rather than hardcoding those names and their replacement placeholder it would be much better to keep this mapping in a separate file like this:

```sh
cat mapping.txt

adam user_1
adam_acc user_3
adam.eve user_2
adam.eve_acc user_4
```

Then use this simple `awk` to get the job done:

```sh
awk 'NR==FNR {map[$1]=$2; next} $NF in map {$NF=map[$NF]} 1' mapping.txt sample.txt

User's name is user_1
Account's name is user_3
User's name is user_2
Account's name is user_4
```

> Edited: 'NR==NR' to 'NR==FNR'

Comment: indeed I was trying to mask bunch of user names, learning how to write shell script for de-identifying and also change references ;)
Appreciate your guide on awk

Comment: I've added an edit as tested using below may you review it, thanks :D

awk 'NR==FNR {map[$1]=$2; next} $NF in map {$NF=map[$NF]} 1' mapping.txt sample.txt

Comment: Hi @anubhava, there is actually no issue with the solutions shared by you for replacing the example: sample.txt

Apologies that I had repicked the accepted answer as I was also looking for other more dynamic solutions whereby it could replace not only one and last word per line "$NF=map[$NF]". 
I've also tried adding quotes on the names in sample.txt and it didn't replace according to the mapping.txt

I believe a more dynamic solution could help more people in community coming from all sort of environment.

Do pardon me that I am still pretty new to awk :D

Comment: This solution doesn't use any regex, it uses string comparison only and it can be easily tweaked as per the requirements. If you edit question state requirements clearly then I can suggest a modified command.